# Calculating the intersection of three circles.

Tags: trigonometry

I'm working on an algorithm that needs to triangulate a sound source.

The system will be using 3 microphones that will be monitoring the sound in the area and display a certain event on a 2D-map.

So... if i have microphones A, B and C, and the source of the sound S.
Lets say A hears the sound first, B second, and C third.

S will be on a circle with radius R around A.

S will be on a circle with radius R + (time difference between A and B * speed of sound) around B.

S will be on a circle with radius R + (time difference between A and C * speed of sound) around C.

The distances between the microphones can change, but can be calculated.

This image below shows an example how it would look.
How can the radius of the circles be calculated and the location of S?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWo3i.png]

Comment: I'm not sure if this question even fits this community ...

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade: why on earth not?

Comment: @RonGordon maybe it needs some more details :)

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade Ill see what i can add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any $3$ reference points $p_1, p_2, p_3$ in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{E}^2$ which are non-collinear and ordered in counterclockwise
orientation, choose a coordinate system such that the centroid of $\triangle p_1p_2p_3$ is the origin. We will abuse the notation to use the same $p$ to denote a point in $\mathbb{E}^2$ and corresponding coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

For any point $p$ with coordinates $(p_x,p_y)$ under this coordinate system, we will use the notation $\vec{p}$ to denote the vector $(p_x,p_y,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We will use $|p|$ and $|\vec{p}|$ to denote the norms for the $2$d-vector $p$ and $3$d-vector $\vec{p}$ respectively.

Let

- $\hat{z}$ be the unit vector $(0,0,1)$.
- $A$ be the area of $\triangle p_1p_2p_3$.
- For any $1 \le i, j \le 3$, let $\rho_i = |p_i|$ and $\ell_{ij} = |p_i - p_j| = 
  |\vec{p}_i - \vec{p}_j|$.
- For any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, let $R$, $k_2$, $k_3$ be the 3 numbers such that
  $$\begin{cases}
  |x-p_1| &= |\vec{x}-\vec{p_1}| = R\\
  |x-p_2| &= |\vec{x}-\vec{p_2}| = R+k_2\\
  |x-p_3| &= |\vec{x}-\vec{p_3}| = R+k_3
  \end{cases}
  $$

The problem at hand is given $k_2, k_3$, how to calculate $R$ and recover the location of $x$.

Consider the tetrahedron formed by $\vec{p}_1, \vec{p}_2, \vec{p}_3$ and $\vec{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since these 4 points lies on the same plane $z = 1$, the tetrahedron is degenerate and its volume $V$ is zero. Since we know the distances among these $4$ points, we can compute its volume using 
[Cayley Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html). This leads to

$$\left|\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & R^2 & (R+k_2)^2 & (R+k_3)^2\\
1 & R^2 & 0 & \ell_{12}^2 & \ell_{13}^2\\
1 & (R+k_2)^2 & \ell_{12}^2 & 0 & \ell_{23}^2\\
1 & (R+k_3)^2 & \ell_{13}^2 & \ell_{23}^2 & 0
\end{matrix}\right| = 288V^2 = 0
$$

If one expand the CM determinant on RHS as a polynomial in $R$, one
will find the coefficients for $R^k$ vanishes for $k > 2$. In fact, if one define
$$\Omega = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2\ell_{13}^2 & \ell_{23}^2 - \ell_{12}^2 - \ell_{13}^2\\
\ell_{23}^2 - \ell_{12}^2 - \ell_{13}^2 & 2\ell_{12}^2
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\Lambda_R = \begin{bmatrix}
2k_2 R + k_2^2 - \ell_{12}^2\\
2k_3 R + k_3^2 - \ell_{13}^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
above condition is equivalent to
$$2R^2 \det\Omega - \Lambda_R^T \Omega \Lambda_R = 0$$
which is clearly a polynomial in $R$ of degree at most $2$.

Once you have $R$, define $$
\begin{cases}
r_1 &= |x-p_1| = |\vec{x}-\vec{p}_1| = R\\
r_2 &= |x-p_2| = |\vec{x}-\vec{p}_2| = R + k_2\\
r_3 &= |x-p_3| = |\vec{x}-\vec{p}_3| = R + k_3
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\begin{cases}
\Delta_1 = r_1^2 - \rho_1^2\\
\Delta_2 = r_2^2 - \rho_2^2\\
\Delta_3 = r_3^2 - \rho_3^2\\
\bar{\Delta} = \frac13 \left(\Delta_1 + \Delta_2 + \Delta_3\right)
\end{cases}
$$
We have
$$r_i^2 = |\vec{x} - \vec{p_i}|^2 = 2 + |x|^2 + |p_i|^2 - 2\vec{x}\cdot\vec{p_i}
\quad\implies\quad \vec{x}\cdot\vec{p_i} = \frac12\left(2 + |x|^2 - \Delta_i\right)
$$
Summing over $i$ and notice 
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 p_3 = (0,0) \implies \sum_{i=1}^3 \vec{p}_i = 3\hat{z}$$
we find $|x|^2 = \bar{\Delta}$ and hence
$\displaystyle\;\vec{x}\cdot\vec{p}_i = \frac12\left( 2 + \bar{\Delta} - \Delta_i \right)$.

Since $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are non-collinear, the 3 vectors $\vec{p}_1$, $\vec{p}_2$, $\vec{p}_3$ are linear independent. We have $\vec{p}_1 \cdot \left( \vec{p}_2 \times \vec{p}_3 \right) = 2 A > 0$. If we define another set of vectors
$$\begin{cases}
\vec{q}_1 = \frac{1}{2A} \left(\vec{p}_2 \times \vec{p}_3 \right)\\
\vec{q}_2 = \frac{1}{2A} \left(\vec{p}_3 \times \vec{p}_1 \right)\\
\vec{q}_3 = \frac{1}{2A} \left(\vec{p}_1 \times \vec{p}_2 \right)
\end{cases}
$$
It is easy to check $\vec{p}_i \cdot \vec{q}_j = \delta_{ij}$ (i.e. $= 1$ or $0$ depends on $i = j$ or not). Using these set of relations, one can show

$$\vec{x} = \sum_{i=1}^3 (\vec{x}\cdot\vec{p}_i) \vec{q}_i
= \frac12\sum_{i=1}^3\left(2+\bar{\Delta} - \Delta_i\right) \vec{q}_i
$$
Notice for $1 \le i \le 3$, 
$$\vec{p}_i \cdot \left( \sum_{j=1}^3 \vec{q}_i - \hat{z} \right)
  = \sum_{j=1}^3 \delta_{ij} - 1 = 0$$
This implies $\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 \vec{q}_j = \hat{z}$ and hence
$\vec{x} = \left(1 + \frac12\bar{\Delta}\right)\hat{z} - \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^3 \Delta_i \vec{q}_i$. From this, we can conclude

> The $2$d-coordinate for the point $x$ is simply the $xy$-component of the $3$d-vector $-\frac12\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 \Delta_i \vec{q}_i$.